# Report with access "everyone (includes anonymous)" not displaying correctly

Tags: civireport

Civicrm 5.2.2 Wordpress 4.9

I have created a report and given access to "everyone (includes anonymous)" and also given view reports permission to anonymous user.
This is the URL https://leep.ngo/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/report/instance/170&reset=1

Only part of the report appears - image below
I have tried reverting to standard twenty sixteen theme with same result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want ANONYMOUS USER to view the report then you need to set the permission in your ACL

Administer -> Userss and Permissions -> Permissions (Access Control)

where you will find "CiviReport: access CiviReport" remove for ANONYMOUS USER

Also for the display you need to make changes in your Theme

I Guess this helps !!! Please feel free to contact me if you need more help

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but permissions are not an issue - I want anonymous user to view the report - and they can  - sort of - I don't think it is a theme issue as it doesn't work with twentyfourteen and reports display fine with this theme on the demo site. I'm going to try disabling plugins and see if that helps

Comment: You are referring to the list box - partial display right?

Comment: Nope not the list box - the report is not displaying